# Android App Signing Process - Hash not matching Facebook API Stored Hash

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, hash

I'm using Ionic and Firebase to make a hybrid app for Android and iOS. I'm going to run through the entire process of how I'm signing the app. I'm doing it manually because when I run `ionic cordova run android` it generates a `android-debug.apk` that's already signed, and I have no clue what the heck it's signing it with.

1. First I make my own key:

   `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias debug -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

This gives me debug.keystore

2. Then I get the SHA1 hash so I can add to Google Firebase, (and I'm sure this command is doing some other useful things, like making ionic always use this for signing purposes when it builds the app):

   `keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias debug -storepass <password> -keypass <password>`

This gives me 12:23:34:45:56:67:78:...

3. Next I run `keytool` to get the regular ol' hash, I don't know what it's called, I guess it's MD5:

   `keytool -exportcert -alias debug -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

This gives me (made up for example): EJHjhsdf9804hjHSDfhf8= I add this in Facebook dev console. It's saved, it's been there for days.

4. Then I need an `.apk` to sign. I have to run the command `ionic cordova build android` or `ionic cordova run android`.

This gives me *android-debug.apk* which is signed for some reason. I checked the 
*/platforms/android* folder and saw a *debug-signing.properties* files that gave the exact location of my `debug.keystore`. So I'm thinking it must be signing it properly. So my *android-debug.apk* must be signed with my key.

So I run the app on my android device, initiate Facebook login and I get:

*screenshot removed But it said your hash (listed hash) doesn't match our hash. Go fk yourself.*

I have never seen this hash anywhere. What the heck, it should be signing with my debug.keystore, which when I run the keytool on it equals (ex.) EJHjhsdf9804hjHSDfhf8=. This doesn't make sense.

Perhaps if I could get a hash of an already signed .apk, then I could know what the hell signed it. Theoretically, it should be my debug.keystore, but apparently Facebook doesn't think that.

Any guidance, please?

*post-edit* -> All sources say to run `keytool` on your `debug.keystore` and that's the hash you put everywhere, but it seems Firebase or Facebook or something knows how to create it's own hash of the app to compare to the hash stored in Facebook dev console.

***EDIT***

I just added the hash in that screenshot to the Facebook dev console, and now my app works.

**SO**, this proves that I guess I'm not in control of signing my apps. Or maybe I'm doing this the wrong way. Wouldn't getting a hash of a `.keystore` give you a different hash than if you got a hash of a `.apk`? Isn't hash generated off of file size or something? Or content? ***Is there a way to get a "key hash" of a signed apk?***

Running your app, getting the error message, then adding that error message hash to the FB dev console isn't an effective way of running an app.

To add, I made a `build.json` file that ionic is using to build the apks. Here's the build process text:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.604 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/.../ionic-project/project/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141
No target specified, deploying to device 'myphone123'.

Reading build config file: C:\Users\...\ionic-project\project\build.json

Reading the keystore from: C:\Users\...\ionic-project\project\debug.keystore
Skipping build...
Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/.../ionic-project/project/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Using apk: C:/Users/.../ionic-project/project/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

Package name: com.kennyhall.project
LAUNCH SUCCESS

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
```

and *`build.json`*

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "debug.keystore",
            "storePassword": "password",
            "alias": "debug",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": ""
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "release.keystore",
            "storePassword": "password",
            "alias": "release",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy this key hash and remove the old key hash and see if it works.

Comment: I did, and it does work. So weird, huh? I've updated question. Idk why I can't seem to get the proper hash.

Comment: The point is that either you maybe getting the debug hash key or your app is still not a signed apk. Though the process looks fine.
Shall I add the answer?

Comment: Well, the signing process is definitely working properly, because I got authenticaion using Google Plus working. I even tested further by generating a new `.keystore` and Google Plus auth wouldn't work. I ran a SHA1 hash on the keystore and put it in Google Firebase, and viola, the Google Play auth worked. So that means Facebook is doing some weird things to authorize, or somehow generating the wrong hash.